# How to Plot Data Faster

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, tcpclient

I want to plot all the data points, I get from the TCP server. But I could not figure out a way to plot all the data points. Instead currently I print the string to the text box. From the text box only the first line is printed.
This is a real time data plotting for  an oscilloscope GUI.
How can I plot all the values.

I tested with a sine wave with a I2S mic, it gave a distorted signal when plotted with the following code.

```
int t;

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    one = new Thread(test);
    one.Start();
    t++;
}

public void test()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    var readCount = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    string datastring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    txtdata.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => txtdata.Text = datastring.Substring(0, 100)));
    
    txtno.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => 
        txtno.Text = ("\nnumber of bytes read: " + readCount)
    ));

    String ch1 = txtdata.Text; ;
    String[] ch1y = ch1.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int a = 1; a < ch1y.Length - 1; a++)
    {
        chart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t, Convert.ToDouble(ch1y[a]))
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the interval of the timer?

Comment: 1 millisecond @ChrisSchaller.

Comment: Does your method complete in that time-frame, I suspect you could easily be getting a race condition

Comment: What is the `client` anyway?

Comment: client is the PC and server is ESP32 module @ChrisSchaller

Comment: @ChrisSchaller what  I want is to get the data from the ESP32 to and plot these data in a chart. This is what I am going to do.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller once this original string is used, the data on the graph plotted once and stop. It is not getting updated. SO does in the text box also. even in the presence of timer tick it doesn't work. I am new to c# programming. Can you help me in this.

Comment: OK, thats actually what I feared. this will depend greatly on what the sketch is inside the _espy_ as I like to call them. Normally you would be running some FFT script to process the readings from the ADC into an array of imaginary numbers, that is what you would be passing back to c# via the serial link. You should post the actual string that it is returning.

Comment: Your problem is at a more conceptual level, if the ESP32 is reporting _instantaneous_ readings then unless you call it at very discrete intervals, the values will not look like what you expect, for instance a 2KHz _sine wave_ is not going to look like the oscilloscope at all if you only sample every millisecond, that wave form would have completed 2 cycles in a single millisecond!

Comment: Whatever output you get from the ESP32, it will usually be in some sort of compressed form or will describe a discrete interval, it won't usually be a single value that you can just plot in an X,Y chart. In Audio processing we talk about packets or a sample of readings. You might want to post some links to the documentation that you are basing this code from but either way this is not a good forum for this type of logic, you should try [iot.se] and look into FFT Visualisations

Comment: Note that the  Timer control has a resolution of only 20-30ms; setting Interval=1 makes no sense !

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not how fast you plot the data, but the fact that you are trying to plot real-time analogue values using a non-uniform asynchronous pattern.

It sounds like you are trying to approach this from a *First Principals* perspective but you are skipping a lot of background understanding that is necessary to pull this off.

The oscilloscope has many functions that allow you to focus in on the specific width or length of the *analogue* sample that you see on the display, this might represent a tiny sample of *audio*, the amplitude of the line in the display usually represents the voltage of the electrical pulse at a *relative* point in time, not a specific point in time.

If your *sine wave* represents a constant 2KHz, and you can see 2 peaks (and 2 troughs) on the screen then you are actually looking at the data captured over an interval of 1ms, to draw a wavy line like that in a chart requires many points, so your initial attempt to plot this as a single X,Y ordinate is going to need many, hundreds perhaps, of discrete points over 1 ms to render the same sort of line, but you would also have to be extra specially careful to ensure that the x interval represented the exact amount of time, or the points you plot will not be in the right place in respect to the time the value was sampled.

> This frequency of processing is not something you want to try to achieve with C#, that would need to be done way down at the hardware level.

The ESP32 you are using to *sample* the *analogue* input will be capturing a specific packet of data at a specific interval, you may have seen phrases like *8-Bit 16Khz Mono* to describe audio quality.

Depending on what processing is going on in the ESP32, the bytes that you receieve will usually represent the total sample, we then need to use the *bitness* to determine how to break the bytes into an *array* of values, it is not a single value.

So 8-Bit Mono means that every 8 bits will represent a single value, so in this case each byte is a separate value. *Mono* means that this is a 1 dimensional array of values, in *Stereo* or 2 channel *interleaved* the bytes represents 2 separate arrays of values, so every second byte actually goes into the second array...

So you don't simply convert the bytes to text using UTF8 Encoding, you need to use other libraries, like NAudio to decode this, you can try it manually though.

In simple c# terms, assuming 8-bit mono, you could plot the entire sample using the array index as `X` and the byte value at the x index as `Y`, however this still isn't going to quite match what you see in the oscilloscope.

Instead have a think about what you actually want to see on the screen, do some research into using Fast Fourier Transform calculations (FFT) to analyse the analog readings, there are even ways to do this directly on the ESP32 which may reduce the processing you do in the C# code.

Comment: I edited the code. Instead of running a thread, I plot the graph at each timer.tick event. now it is bit ok. But still not looks like a sine wave. I think here the problem is during two tick points, not being able to plot all the points in order to get a smooth signal. How can I plot in that manner @ChrisSchaller

Comment: isn't it the thing done in ```String[] ch1y = ch1.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int a = 1; a < ch1y.Length - 1; a++)
    {
        chart1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t, Convert.ToDouble(ch1y[a]))
        ));```

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the baud rate. The wave shows almost a pure sine wave at 2kHz wave after that. But only the 2kHz wave looks like that. instead of running a thread, the chart was plotted for each clock tick with `Add` command.